# Point domains to my new virtual server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a virtual server running on Windows Server 2008. How do I point my domains to look at the server.

I have a domain ready to be used for a nameserver but I only have 1 ip address for the server, do I need 2 IP addresses?

On the server I have enabled DNS Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your DNS replication with your domain, and your forwarders setup correctly, you should only need to add the IP address of your new server to your DHCP scope and add that as your DNS server on any static ip addresses you have on your network.

You don't *need* two IP addresses.

Comment: Ok Sorry. I am very new to DNS and nameserver configuration. In my fasthosts control panel I have added "glue records" to one of my domains in an attempt to use it as my nameserver. It said i had to create a minimum of 2 so i created ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com and i pointed them both to my server IP address. I haven't done anything else on the server yet. What do i need to do now?

Comment: Alright, you're definitly all over the board here of what you are looking to do. Is this fasthost you're talking about http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/login/? That sounds like a public record of where people would be trying to find your information. Like if someone from the internet wants to access your web site www.yourdomain.com or mail.yourdomain.com, etc. Are you talking about that, or an internal DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

If you used Namebased hosting then one IP address would be enough. You would only need more IP address if you are using IP based hosting.

Check for IIS configuration for names based hosting.